# How to decrease datatable row height in primefaces

Tags: primefaces, datatable, height, row

I tried to decrease the height of the column by using following syntax:

```
<p:column style="height:10px;">
```

and the datatable row height won't decrease; it only increases if I set a bigger size.

Is there a way to make the height smaller than the default/existing one?

This is the exact code, that I'm using:

```
<c:forEach var="column" items="#{dispoFillingPage.columnListAuftrag}">
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${column.dateColumn}">
                            <p:column id="#{column.id}" filterStyleClass="#{column.filterStyleClass}" headerText="#{column.title}" visible="#{column.visible}"
                                width="#{column.width}" filterBy="#{data[column.property]}" sortBy="#{data[column.property]}" field="#{column.property}"
                                filterFunction="#{standortPage.filterByDate}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="height:10px">
                                <f:attribute name="rtcCol" value="#{column}" />
                                <h:outputText value="#{data[column.property]}">
                                    <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
                                </h:outputText>
                            </p:column>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <p:column id="#{column.id}" filterStyleClass="#{column.filterStyleClass}" headerText="#{column.title}" field="#{column.property}"
                                visible="#{column.visible}" width="#{column.width}" filterBy="#{data[column.property]}" sortBy="#{data[column.property]}"
                                filterMatchMode="contains" style="height:10px;">
                                <f:attribute name="rtcCol" value="#{column}" />
                                <h:outputText value="#{data[column.property]}" />
                            </p:column>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                </c:forEach>
```

I have to do this, because I have two datatables with 20 rows each and I have to make them fit in the screen, so that they are entirely visible to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to decrease the font-style of the datatable in order to decrease also the row height.

```
<p:datatable style="font-size:8px">
```

But this way I decrease the entire datatable.

Comment: Then learn some more basic css... Apply a class and create a selector that only works on `<tr>` inside the datatable 'data' body....